# Why is the Spark property spark.sql.optimizer.metadataOnly being deprecated

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I got a warning upon setting `spark.sql.optimizer.metadataOnly` to true. I use this property mainly for querying partition columns without reading the parquet files. It is very useful to figure which partitions to read, for example getting distinct values from a partition column very quickly.

How would `SparkSessionExtensions` work to keep this property in the future, or is there an alternative way to query partition columns without reading the data files? (I code in pyspark.)

```
WARN SQLConf: The SQL config 'spark.sql.optimizer.metadataOnly' has been deprecated in Spark v3.0 and may be removed in the future. Avoid to depend on this optimization to prevent a potential correctness issue. If you must use, use 'SparkSessionExtensions' instead to inject it as a custom rule.
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that it can produce incorrect results, it would need to be implemented some other way.
The deprecation is to follow the policy of giving some notice before removing a feature.
See details: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-31647

The alternative is to query directly the underlying catalog client (e.g. Hive or Glue clients)